# How to identify whether a function is executing or not in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

Suppose

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report.dummy_func1() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_sleep(10);
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;   

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report.dummy_func() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    PERFORM pg_sleep(5);
    PERFORM report.dummy_func1();
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;   

Select report.dummy_func();
```

With the above setup,  is there a way to identify which function is currently being executed?

One way to identify is using **pg_stat_activity**, but it doesn't show which function is being executed.

Is there a reliable way to find whether a function is executing or not in postgresql.

My original requirement is to invoke a function, only if it is not already running. Is there a better way to achieve this in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My original requirement is to invoke a function, only if it is not already running. Is there a better way to achieve this in postgresql?

It sounds like you should be using an advisory lock:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html

Basically, something like:

```
if not pg_try_advisory_lock(_key) then return -1; end if;
-- do stuff...
perform pg_advisory_unlock(_key);
```